# Can I stop revisiond from accessing my external drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, spotlight

I have an external RAID drive and its kind of noisy when in use. Many mornings it makes a lot of noise because something is accessing it. At first I thought it was spotlight so I configured spotlight to ignore it. Now I see another process named `revisiond` is accessing it:

```
$ sudo lsof -n | grep GlyphRaid
mds          94               root   17r      DIR               1,13         476           2 /Volumes/GlyphRaid
revisiond   125               root    6r      DIR               1,13         476           2 /Volumes/GlyphRaid
revisiond   125               root   11r      DIR               1,13         306         823 /Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100
revisiond   125               root   12u      REG               1,13       98304         828 /Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100/.cs/ChunkStoreDatabase
revisiond   125               root   14u      REG               1,13           0         830 /Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100/.cs/ChunkStoreDatabase-wal
revisiond   125               root   15u      REG               1,13       86016         831 /Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100/db-V1/db.sqlite
revisiond   125               root   16u      REG               1,13        8272         833 /Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100/db-V1/db.sqlite-wal
```

Here is the process:

```
$ ps aux | grep revisiond
root               125   0.0  0.1  4863800  26548   ??  Ss   Mon08AM   0:00.49 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/Support/revisiond
```

For some reason it is tracking changes made with system tools (e.g., Preview):

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/GlyphRaid/.DocumentRevisions-V100/AllUIDs/7/com.apple.documentVersions
$ sudo ls -al
total 0
d--x--x--x  3 _unknown  _unknown     102 Aug  6 10:17 .
d--x--x--x  3 _unknown  _unknown     102 Aug  6 10:17 ..
-r--r--r--@ 1 _unknown  _unknown  366872 Aug  6 10:04 B29AD895-96BC-4D98-886B-38022A323FCC.png
```

This is absolutely intolerable! Can I safely kill this process or is there some way to stop it from running? I don't see it anywhere in the system startup scripts.

Comment: I have stopped other daemons like geod and photoanalysisd from running altogether with `sudo launchctl stop system/geod` and `sudo launchctl remove system/geod`. I need to do it at each reboot. Maybe it will work for your revisiond, too.  If you can figure out the "service target", then you can also `sudo launchctl disable {target}` and `sudo launchctl unload -F {taget}` which should keep it from ever coming back. (I couldn't find a 'target' for 'geod'.) Also, `man revisiond` says: *There are no configurations to revisiond*...

Comment: @aMike thanks -- I am not sure what the right target is either ... If I do a hard kill (`kill -9`) it just respawns. I can't find any info on `revisiond` other than the brief man page you mention. I've unmounted the drive for know. I'll try bringing it back up later...

Comment: If you're not on a locked-down system, maybe you could tweak /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.revisiond.plist  to turn it off - but that will affect all "revisions" on the system. From google results, it seems some folks have had success with booting in to Safe Mode and then back into regular mode... I made a "nogeo" shell script to turn of 'geod' - I just have to remember to run it wheneven I reboot.  I'm also wondering if it's like spotlight and will eventually finish its work and stop. Good luck!

Comment: Also... maybe see what this shows when 'revisiond' is thrashing: `sudo opensnoop -n revisiond`.  And check the Console logs (maybe have to be admin user to see them all?) to see what's happening there.

Comment: No matter what I do mds and revisiond constantly spin on my external backup disk.  I have told Spotlight to ignore the disk using both the Settings GUI and mdutil, but it persists.